# How to set auxiliary command on ONVIF protocol?

Tags: c#, onvif

I have a trouble with ONVIF protocol.

I am making the camera controller on the ONVIF protocol using the C#. and  I can find some ONVIF protocol doc. but that doc has no how to configure auxiliary command.

The one of the doc is https://www.onvif.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/ONVIF_PTZ_Client_Test_Specification_v1706.pdf.

The next one of the doc is https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/ptz/ONVIF-PTZ-Service-Spec-v260.pdf.

And I have a sad article has a comment that "As result, from the VMS' GUI it is not possible to activate the Wiper, to run the Washing procedure, or to switch the camera to Night Mode.". https://support.videotec.com/hc/en-gb/articles/204773035-How-to-manage-Special-Functions-using-ONVIF

So, Really can not External program set the auxiliary command???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, but here's a piece of code using the ptz module of the ONVIF protocol...

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1192709/ONVIF-PTZ-Control-in-Csharp

You're supposed to be able to get a list of possible AUX command throught the `GetNode` function of the ptz ver20 .wsdl

https://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl

You should then be able to use the `SendAuxiliaryCommand` form the same .wsdl

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks to your answer, But I'm already done this issue using the camera Internal protocol.